# My app not showing by default in Samsung game launcher

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing android game in unity and I'm wondering how I can make my game show by default in game launcher (which is available by default in some samsung devices(e.g. Galaxy s8).

My game is "marked as game" in unity player settings and the game is published on google play (beta testing right now).

After installation the game is not showing in game launcher, I'm not sure if I release full version of my game (not beta) it'll be listed as a game.

Any knowledge on this topis would be helpful.

Comment: Do you find answer?, is there any solution?

Comment: I forgot about it, and I don't know if it is connected with any changes that I've made or just the fact of going out of beta - now my app is automatically moved to the game launcher after the installation.